# How to Add a Watermark to Http live streaming HLS files

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark, http-live-streaming

We have about 2000 movies that are streamed to HLS format. each movie is in a folder with one `.m3u8` file and lots of `.ts` files. is there any way to add our `Watermark.png` to all these movies without re-encoding to `.mp4` files using `ffmpeg`  ?

Comment: If you want the watermark imprinted, you'll have to re-encode. But you can re-encode to HLS.

Comment: @Mulvya but it takes a long time, whats the fastest way to convert MP4 or MKV to HLS ? currently any movie takes about 2 hours

Comment: I don't see a way around it. At best, you can encode using GPU or use a fast preset with libx264.

Comment: I there any new feature update that can support this now? @Gyan Time is very crucial for my use case